# Issue passing newline `\n` character to curl command

Tags: curl, newlines, stderr

My Jenkins multiline parameter is read in a variable `SERVER_IP`  which is passed to Unix `curl` command as below:

The curl command triggers a webpage(Jenkins Build) and passes the parameters to the webpage.

```
curl  -k -X POST 'https://user1:118f32aa48601c10e107f5@portal.myshopb.com:9043/job/Scanner/buildWithParameters?SERVER_IP=192.118.89.106\n10.9.20.13\n10.0.23.121&USER=root&REPORT_NAME=ihs_run' -H "Jenkins-Crumb:8c6f641ab7b9d1e7839c17a2be844490f2c88c5f9ae90c5ae5d52d7eae1"
```

I get the below error executing the curl command:

> curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Unfortunately; I do not have control over changing the SERVER_IP variable.

How can I get my curl command to pass the SERVER_IP values as is avoiding the error.

Comment: If you need the IP addresses to be newline-delimited, then possibly URL encode each newline as `%0A`?

Comment: `https://www.urlencoder.org/` tells me the URL encode for `\n` is `%5Cn` . Am I correct ?

Comment: `%5Cn` would be the literal string `\n` ("backslash followed by `n`"). If this is what you want to send over, then use that. If you want `\n` to be a newline, then use `%0A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo 'https://user1:118f32aa48601c10e107f5@portal.myshopb.com:9043/job/Scanner/buildWithParameters?SERVER_IP='${SERVER_IP}'&USER=root&REPORT_NAME=ihs_run' -H "Jenkins-Crumb:8c6f641ab7b9d1e7839c17a2be844490f2c88c5f9ae90c5ae5d52d7eae1" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' | xargs curl -k -X POST`

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) provides a good explanation on the sed command used in this example. I simply added `\\n` to stay inline with what I thought you wanted as a result. The sanatized version of the URL is then piped to `xargs` who will build and execute the command line from stdin.

As an example, the following would create a dir named one nesting dir two.

`echo 'one/two' | xargs mkdir -p` same as -> `mkdir -p one/two`

Hope that is clear. Glad it helped you out.

Comment: My code is like so `curl  -k -X POST 'https://user1:118f32aa48601c10e107f5@portal.myshopb.com:9043/job/Scanner/buildWithParameters?SERVER_IP=$SERVER_IP&USER=root`

So, how can i put ` <<EOF` in between  the IPs `192.118.89.106 <<EOF
10.9.20.13
10.0.23.121`  like how it is suggested in the answer ? @1nternetz

Comment: Kindly suggest @1nternetz as the answer does not help my case.

Comment: The --data-binary flag lets you feed curl data as-is.
The @- or - tells curl to consume input from stdin.
<<EOF is the end of stream indicator. This means it will consume everything until it hits EO, hence <<EOF would not appear in your code.

Another trick could be GNU Bash ANSI C escaping.
SERVER_IP=$'192.118.89.106\n10.10.9.13\n10.0.23.121'&USER=root

Notice the single quotes after the $. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if I m not able to understand. I don't have to tell curl to consume from `stdin` as the data is stored in `SERVER_IP` variable. As suggested, I tried the following command which fails: 

`curl --data-binary -k -X POST 'https://user1:118f32aa48601c10e107f5@portal.myshopb.com:9043/job/Scanner/buildWithParameters?SERVER_IP=$SERVER_IP&USER=root&REPORT_NAME=ihs_run' -H "Jenkins-Crumb:8c6f641ab7b9d1e7839c17a2be844490f2c88c5f9ae90c5ae5d52d7eae1"`

I get the following error: 
`command not found: 10.9.20.13
command not found: 10.0.23.121`

@1nternetz

Comment: Sorry, missread. I though you wanted to generate new lines in your curl command.

Could you do something like this: ```echo 'https://user1:118f32aa48601c10e107f5@portal.myshopb.com:9043/job/Scanner/buildWithParameters?SERVER_IP='${SERVER_IP}'&USER=root&REPORT_NAME=ihs_run'  -H "Jenkins-Crumb:8c6f641ab7b9d1e7839c17a2be844490f2c88c5f9ae90c5ae5d52d7eae1" | sed  ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' | xargs curl -k -X POST```

Comment: works !! Can you post this as an answer and also explain what is that you are doing in `sed` command ?

Comment: this works!! Can you please post this as an answer and also explain what all are you doing with the `sed` command

Comment: Hello @Ashar, I have modified my initial answer. Thanks.